# I want another version package (Python)

Tags: python

I used `discord.py` and `r6sapi`.
But two packages used `aiohttp`.

`discord.py` needs `aiohttp<3.8.0, >=3.6.0`
`r6sapi` needs `aiohttp<3.0.0, >=2.3.3`

how to use two packages same time?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to run multiple versions of python on your machine and switch between them, I think the information in the link below might help
https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/

Comment: No, they want to install two versions of the same library and use it from a single piece of code.